# Memory not released properly when trying to delete node from linked list

Tags: c, multithreading, locks

I am trying to delete a node from a linked list while using mutexes.
For some reason this works properly without mutexes, but if i add locks, it still keeps some data from the deleted node.
Can anyone please advice?
Here is my code:

```
ptr2=head;
ptr1=ptr2->next;

pthread_mutex_lock(&ptr2->lock);
pthread_mutex_lock(&ptr1->lock);

if( head == NULL){
    fprintf(stderr,"List is empty");
    exit(1);
}

if(record == 1){
    head=head->next;
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&ptr1->lock);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&ptr2->lock);
    free(ptr2);
}
else if (record > 1 && record < list_size){
    while(count <= record-1 && ptr1 ){
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&ptr1->lock);
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&ptr2->lock);*/
        ptr2 = ptr1;
        ptr1 = ptr1->next;
        count++;    
        pthread_mutex_trylock(&ptr2->lock); 
        pthread_mutex_trylock(&ptr1->lock);
    }
    if(ptr1){           
        ptr2->next = ptr2->next->next;
        pthread_mutex_trylock(&ptr2->lock); 
        pthread_mutex_trylock(&ptr1->lock);
    }
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&ptr1->lock);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&ptr2->lock);  
    free(ptr1);
}
else
    printf("\nInvalid record. Please try again");
```

Comment: "Keeps some data from the deleted node" - in what way?

Comment: lets say i have one string and one integer, when i print the list, the name is gone but the integer remains.. the node is actually somehow there but with not all the data of it

Comment: @user9091498 Why are you using `pthread_mutex_trylock` without checking its return value?

Comment: I don't understand this at all.  'ptr2=head;' then head gets changed by another thread and you're done:(

Comment: @Ivan from what i understood, pthread_mutex_trylock will only lock the memory section only if is not already locked right? Martin James i am using this in order to have a reference to the previous node so i can delete the correct one

Comment: @user9091498 And if it is locked? Then you are not locking anything. Overall your locking does not work - you cannot put mutex in a node like this - what if node is being deleted by another thread while you are trying to lock it?

Comment: @user9091498 well, without an MCVE, we don't know the scope of such vars, or how they are protected from multiple accesses, (should they need it), so it's not possible to work out what is going on.

Comment: I fear that I agree with @Ivan.  This all looks very borken to me too:(

Comment: @Ivan but it will be already locked by the thread which tries to delete it.. /it looks like is working, after some sleep() i put, the second thread waits for the first to finish and then it locks the next node. In case this node was deleted from the first thread, then the next node will be set as the next->next

Comment: @user9091498 `pthread_mutex_trylock` is used when threads can try to process some data, but can do something else if lock is not yet available. To implement thread-safe list you usually need to put a single lock guarding the whole list.

Comment: @user9091498 You are freeing both locks before locking mutexes at another set of locks, what if someone removes the node you are trying to lock? It wasn't lock since you unlocked it, so it is possible.

Comment: @Ivan, the initial implementation was this, i was setting a single mutex for the whole list, but i thought that trying to lock the nodes one by one, would be more efficient..

Comment: @Ivan so the only way of removing a node safely from a linked list is only if i lock the list every time?

Comment: @user9091498 You may try to do this using separate mutex per node, but you cannot unlock both mutexes at the same time while walking the list. Plus I am not sure this is justifiable from the performance point of view. It might only worth something if your list is big, but if it is, you probably should not be using list in the first place.

Comment: @Ivan but i am already using different mutexes.. no? i am using the lock from ptr1 and ptr2 to lock.. also if i dont unlock them before i free or before i move them both pointing on the next node, then i will never be able to unlock them.. so mean this will lead to deadlock or something..

Comment: @user9091498 If you are unlocking both mutexes, another thread might come and remove element you are trying to remove. Then your thread will try to remove it again, leading to heap corruption.